Integer points of the expression $\frac{4q}{2q-pq+2p}$ where $p,q\in\mathbb Z$.
This expression is encoded with a geometric meaning as follows. Consider a polyhedron with congruent polygon faces, each with $p$ sides. If there are $F$ number of polygons, that is, faces of the polyhedron, then there are in total $pF/2$ many edges if one assumes the polyhedron is edge-to-edge. If moreover assume that each vertex has the same number, say $q$ many polygons around it, then the polyhedron has $pF/q$ many vertices. If such polyhedron is homeomorphic to $S^2$, then Euler's characteristic tells us$$F-\frac{pF}{2}+\frac{pF}{q}=2.$$Note that $F,p,q$ are all positive. From the first expression, by dividing out the $pF$ one has immediately that $$\frac{2}{\min(p,q)}>\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}>\frac{1}{2},$$or $$\min(p,q)<4.$$ For $(p,q)=(3,3),(3,4),(3,5),(4,3),(5,3)$ these are the Platonic solids. For $p=2$ and $q=2$ there are infinitely many solutions, corresponding to the hosohedron and dihedron as spherical polyhedron. In other words, the function $$F(p,q)=\frac{4q}{2q-pq+2p},$$restricted to the domain $\{2,3,...\}\times\{2,3,...\}$, has only $(2,n)$, $(n,2)$, $(3,3)$, $(3,4)$, $(4,3)$, $(3,5)$, and $(5,3)$ as its positive integer points. For $p=1$ or $q=1$ there are only points $(p,q)= (1,0),(0,1),(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ that could give a positive integer point.
Natually one would think of the extension of this problem:  For integers $p,q$ such that $2p+2q\neq pq$, when is $F(p,q)$ an integer? And what does the solution tells us geometrically?
Some examples: for $p=q=5$, $F(p,q)=-4$ and for $p=q=6$, $F(p,q)=-2$. Actually for $p=q$ the integer points corresponds to exactly $(p,q)=(3,3),(5,5),(6,6),(8,8)$ by some simple calculation. For some $p\neq q$ example, $F(5,6)=-3$.

The case $pq=0$ is uninteresting, so let $p$ and $q$ be nonzero integers such that the fraction
$$\frac{4q}{2q-pq+2p},$$
is an integer. Note that the denominator can be expressed as
$$2q-pq+2p=4-(p-2)(q-2),$$
and so substituting $x:=p-2$ and $y:=q-2$ we find that the fraction
$$\frac{4y+8}{4-xy},\tag{1}$$
is a nonzero integer. If $|x|>4$ and $|y|\geq12$ then
$$|4-xy|>|5y-4|\geq|4y+8|,$$
and so the fraction $(1)$ is not an integer. So either $|x|\leq3$ or $|y|\leq11$, or equivalently, either $-1\leq p\leq5$ or $-9\leq q\leq13$. From here it is a routine check of a few small values.
